# Use 1 function to fade in multiple divs using an ID

Tags: jquery

I need to show/hide multiple divs based on what the user clicks on.

So they click on a link:

```
<a href="#" id="image1">Click me to show</a>
```

Which then shows the div using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#image1").click(function () {
    $("#image1_view").fadeIn();
    return false; 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

What I need to do is do this multiple times so there are multiple links on a page which, when clicked on, show the correct div.

Short of copying & pasting the above code loads of times, what is the easier way to do it? How can I pass an ID of the link to the jQuery so that it knows which div to show?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both links and images have ID's that resemble one another, like:

```
<a href="#" id="image1">Click me to show</a>
<a href="#" id="image2">Click me to show</a>
<a href="#" id="image3">Click me to show</a>

<img src="img1.png" id="image1_view" />
<img src="img2.png" id="image2_view" />
<img src="img3.png" id="image3_view" />
```

etc, you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[id^="image"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('#'+ this.id +'_view').fadeIn().one('click', function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great. I also want to fade the div out once the user clicks on it (i.e. they click to show, then click the div to hide it again). How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can give the `div` elements to be faded in an ID, this should work (pass the ID reference inside the `a` element's `href` attribute):

```
$('a.fadeIn').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    var the_div = $($(this).attr('href'));
    the_div.fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your `<a>` tags dummy css class (ex. ClassName1)

Edit the Code so that it looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ClassName1").click(function () {
    $("#" + this.id + "_view").fadeIn();
    return false; 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

where you maintain the IDs of Divs to be the ImageID_view